# Eclipse Neon quick assist automatically adds @NonNull

Tags: java, eclipse, annotations, eclipse-neon

In my Eclipse Neon workspace settings i checked `[x] Enable annotation-based null analysis`. Now when I'm doing `Assign statement to new variable` from quick assist, Eclipse sometimes adds `@NonNull` to the new variable assigment. So intead of line 1, I get line 2:

```
Deprecated annotation = Main.class.getAnnotation(Deprecated.class); // line 1
@NonNull Deprecated annotation = Main.class.getAnnotation(Deprecated.class); // line 2
```

This raises two questions:

1. How can I enable and disable this behaviour? In a second project within the same workspace Eclipse doesn't to this. So it doesn't only depend on the annotation-based null analysis which was configured in the workspace settings.
2. Why does Eclipse conclude `annotation` is `@NonNull` while the return value can be clearly be `null` (by documentation):

> `java.lang.annotation.Annotation java.lang.Class.getAnnotation(java.lang.Class annotationClass)`
>
> Returns this element's annotation for the specified type if such an annotation is *present*, else null.

Answer (score 2):

You are right, Eclipse computes the wrong null annotation: *@NonNull* instead of *@Nullable*. If you [use external null annotation](http://help.eclipse.org/neon/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/tasks/task-using_external_null_annotations.htm) and annotate the method return type of `java.lang.Class.getAnnotation(Class<A>)` as *@Nullable* then the *Assign statement to new variable* quick fix creates the correct null annotation.

To disable creation of null annotations the `[x] Use default annotations for null specification` (below `[x] Enable annotation-based null analysis`) must be unchecked. Unfortunately, there seems to be another bug: clicking the check box opens the *Annotations for Null Specifications* dialog. As workaround for this bug, specify the primary as secondary annotation and `n.a` as primary annotation for each annotation.

Could you please [report both bugs to Eclipse](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi)?